# Folder is not under version control and is not part of the commit

Tags: ios, xcode, svn

I'm developing an iOS app with XCode 4.2 and latest SDK.

I have added to my project a folder with several files. This folder is a real folder in Finder.

When I try to commit those files I get the following message:

```
svn: Commit failed (details follow):
svn: '/Users/User1/Fuentes/iPhone/Desarrollos/TurismoCR2/TurismoCR2/Descripciones' is not under version control and is not part of the commit, yet its child '/Users/User1/Fuentes/iPhone/Desarrollos/TurismoCR2/TurismoCR2/Descripciones/021es.html' is part of the commit
```

How can I fix this error?

Probably I could add these files and folder manually but I don't know how (and I don't want to make a mistake).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to do:

```
cd /Users/User1/Fuentes/iPhone/Desarrollos/TurismoCR2/TurismoCR2
```

then:

```
svn add Descripciones/
```

Comment: I tried it with mi folder, but in the terminal i get:`svn: warning: 'livelli' is already under version control.`

Xcode still say that's not true...

Comment: Same thing for me! In my case I had added a file in a folder and then deleted it manually. I had to do svn rm --force /path/to/file to get this to work.

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

step 1:
svn ci

step 2:
Then vim or vi will be automatically offered by the svn (with svn diff file name) then type the required string or massage and save it.

Done.

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow.  This question already has an accepted answer and was asked 10 months ago.  Please also refrain from "this will rock" in your answer.  I hope you stick around and answer some other questions.